# VB Script, modifying the body of a text whilst maintaining formatting

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2010

I want to use VBscript to open a template(or .msg), edit the body of the text whilst preserving the formatting and then finally sending the email.

the email has a section in it called "insert date" where I want to insert a date.

here is some code I currently have:

```
Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set msg = ol.CreateItemFromTemplate([location of template file] 

Set doc = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor 

If Not doc Is Nothing Then 
    doc.application.selection.find.execute _ 
        "insert date", , , , , , , , , DateValue(Now() - Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) - 2), wdReplaceAll 
End If
```

Unfortunately this does not replace the text but instead just appears to highlight the text and I am unable to do anything further.

Another related question:
I am new to coding, I used VBScript because I have come from VBA where I was doing a very similar thing to a document. It appears that VBScript is not only restrictive but also I dont find it extremely easy to use (maybe because it isnt very powerful?)
Is there another language that I can use to automate this sort of thing and interacting with outlook?
Perhaps Python but I am not sure where to get started with Microsoft Office integration.
note: I am sure many coding languages will be able to do this but I am restricted with what I can use at work so any less well known languages will certainly not be supported :(

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea about vbs (or alternatives)....

but as you tagged this with outlook-vba, there I am doing something alike with this code:

```
mailitem.HTMLBody = Replace(mailitem.HTMLBody, "text old", "text new" & now())
```

You can also use html-tags to make the text bold, bigger or something.

Max

Comment: Hello Max, thanks for replying :) when I use this method, it works but it creates double line spacing for some reason. it appears to add space before and after each line and it also removes some highlighting. I am not sure why this occurs but I dont know how to prevent it from occuring. Additionally, I dont know how to change those parts back with a macro.
The original text is composed in RTF format.

Comment: can you upload the template sonewhere for me? wht do you mean with "with a macro" - as mentioned I can only help in vba, and there I am almost a beginner ;-)